# multiple contour plot with normalization in python

Tags: python, seaborn, colorbar

I try to multiple kde plot with seaborn in python.
but in a kde plot, normalization is complete in an axis.

I want to compare axes in a color bar (same colorbar).
But I get this message

> AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'autoscale_None'

xs[i] or ys[i] is simple float list
total code:

```
lim_ = 2
f, axarr = plt.subplots(2, 3, figsize=(12,8)
    #                         , sharex=True, sharey=True
                           )
axl = [axarr[0,0],axarr[0,1],axarr[1,0],axarr[1,1],axarr[0,2]]

for i in range(len(arrays_)):
    ax = axl[i]
    fname = flist[i]
    n_ptc = n_ptcs[i]
    im = sns.kdeplot(np.asarray(xs[i]),np.asarray(ys[i])
                     ,shade=True, shade_lowest=False
                     ,cut = 3, gridsize = 100
                     ,clip=(-lim_,lim_)
                     ,ax = ax
                    )
ax = axarr[1,2]
ax.set_axis_off()
cbar = ax.figure.colorbar(im, ax=ax)
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('densty', rotation=-90, va="bottom")
```

[image]

Comment: I can tell you *why* you have that error message: it is because `sns.kdeplot()` returns an `Axes` object (`ax`), and not a "mappable" as `fig.colorbar()` is expecting. What I cannot figure out is what you are trying to achieve. The colorbar for each of the subplot is probably going to be different, so which are you trying to display?

Comment: you should be able to add `sns.kdeplot(..., cbar=True)` to your code to get 6 color bars next to each plot, at least to see if they are the same range

Comment: @DizietAsahi , I want to use only one colorbar for comparing all sup-figures with the same color and same range.